# Start a repeating alarm that performs a background service only if it isn't running already

Tags: android, alarm

I have an alarm that is started inside the onCreate() method of the MainActivity. It performs a background service that periodically fetches data from the internet every 20 minutes. It works okay. But the problem is that every time the user exits the application and opens it again, the alarm is set again and the background service is started. So, there are multiple alarms running and the services are run at random intervals. How do I start the alarm only if one isn't running already? I've searched on the internet and found something called `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` but I can't seem to use it properly. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my Alarm code which is inside the onCreate() method.

```
/**** CODE FOR BACKGROUND SERVICE ****/

    Intent alarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating
                (AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1200000, pendingIntent);


    /**** END CODE FOR BACKGROUND SERVICE ****/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` . Have you tried to implement it like this?

```
/**** CODE FOR BACKGROUND SERVICE ****/

    Intent alarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    // Check if the alarm receiver is currently active
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if(alarmRunning == false) {
        // Alarm is not running. Set it up
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating
                (AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1200000, pendingIntent);
    }
    else {
        // Alarm is running..
        Log.d("ALARM TAG", "Alarm is already running. Do nothing.");
    }

    /**** END CODE FOR BACKGROUND SERVICE ****/
```